# Mysql 5.1 Does Not Use Index On Joining With the Results of a Select

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query like:

```
select * from x join (
    select * from y join z on y.id=z.id
) as t on x.name = t.name
```

This query takes 5 minutes in mysql `5.1`, while with the same dataset it takes only 100 milli seconds on mysql `5.7`. Mysql `5.1` is is not honoring the fact that name column is a key in all the tables. Basically all the tables have the column `name` and they are indexed:

```
KEY `name_index` (`name`),
```

I have tried using force index to persuade the server to use the index, no avail. Meaning that both versions complain about the syntax.

```
select * from x join (
    select * from y join z on y.id=z.id
) as t force index(`name_index`) on x.name = t.name
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'force index(`name_index`) on x.name = t.name' at line 3

Does anyone know any workaround to force mysql to use an index on the results of a join?

Comment: You might want to include the table definitions (as one-liners) for all tables.

Comment: Optimizations have improved in the 5.5, 5.6, 5.7.  I can't point to the one that improved this query.  For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: As for the `name_index  `, you seem to have spelled it differently.

Comment: The sub-query you have can be converted to normal join. I think your mysql 5.1 might be able to use indexes in this case.

Comment: All the codes are contrived. Query is supposed to be written this way. I have copied and pasted the index name, so I am sure there are no typos involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the subquery into join and so your outdated MySQL 5.1 might be able to use index in this case.

```
SELECT
    x.*
FROM
    x
    INNER JOIN y ON (
        x.name = y.name -- It is not clear from original query where is the derived name cone from
    )
    INNER JOIN z ON (
        y.id = z.id
    )
```